# Find and replace list items with list item python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have list as follows:

```
c11=[' YandexBot/3.0, +http://yandex.com/bots', ' Win64, x64', ' AhrefsBot/5.2, +http://ahrefs.com/robot/', ' Android 7.1.2, Redmi 4 Build/N2G47H', ' Android 7.0, EVA-L09 Build/HUAWEIEVA-L09', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi Note 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Googlebot/2.1, +http://www.google.com/bot.html', ' Android 6.0.1, CPH1701 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-J500F Build/MMB29M', ' uCrawler/1.0 , +https://blog.ucoz.ru/upolicy', ' SurdotlyBot/1.0, +http://sur.ly/bot.html', ' Opera Mini/8.0.40377/85.73, U', ' Pinterestbot/1.0, +http://www.pinterest.com/bot.html', ' Android 7.0, SM-J701F Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0.1, Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-A500H Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.1.1, SM-T385 Build/NMF26X', ' SemrushBot/1.2~bl, +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html', ' Android 6.0.1, ONE A2003 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.0, Redmi Note 4 Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0, QMobile X32 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 5.1.1, SM-J200F Build/LMY47X', ' WOW64, rv:40.0', ' Android 6.0, IK-7216 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 7.0, SM-J710FN Build/NRD90M']
```

Now i have another list as follows:

```
ww=["http://yandex.com/bots',", "http://ahrefs.com/robot/',", "http://www.google.com/bot.html',", "https://blog.ucoz.ru/upolicy',", "http://sur.ly/bot.html',", "http://www.pinterest.com/bot.html',", "http://www.semrush.com/bot.html',"]
```

The values in ww is also in c11 , i want to find and replace the values in c11 with ''(empty string) if those values are matches/exists in any element of ww. (i.e) any element of ww matches with or contains values in c11, we need to replace the value to an empty string.

like

```
for i in ww:
  re.sub(i,'',str(c11))
```

Can any body suggest using re module

I am expecting following output :

```
   c11=[' YandexBot/3.0, ', ' Win64, x64', ' AhrefsBot/5.2, ', ' Android 7.1.2, Redmi 4 Build/N2G47H', ' Android 7.0, EVA-L09 Build/HUAWEIEVA-L09', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi Note 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Googlebot/2.1, ', ' Android 6.0.1, CPH1701 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-J500F Build/MMB29M', ' uCrawler/1.0 , ', ' SurdotlyBot/1.0, ', ' Opera Mini/8.0.40377/85.73, U', ' Pinterestbot/1.0, ', ' Android 7.0, SM-J701F Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0.1, Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-A500H Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.1.1, SM-T385 Build/NMF26X', ' SemrushBot/1.2~bl, ', ' Android 6.0.1, ONE A2003 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.0, Redmi Note 4 Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0, QMobile X32 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 5.1.1, SM-J200F Build/LMY47X', ' WOW64, rv:40.0', ' Android 6.0, IK-7216 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 7.0, SM-J710FN Build/NRD90M']
```

Comment: What would be the expected output in your sample case? And since you asked specifically for a regex solution, you should include the `regex` tag.

Comment: you think words in `ww` are in `c11`, but they aren't. Note single quote `'` at the end of each word in ww. For example `"http://yandex.com/bots',"` is not in `' YandexBot/3.0, +http://yandex.com/bots'`

Comment: Site is not allowing me to add re tag , its says i need 1500 points

Comment: @honda, post the expected result

Comment: Why not post expected output?

Comment: expected output added in the question , kindly take a look

Comment: Why do u have `,'` at the end of each string in `c11` array?

Comment: see properly its ', not  ,' its separating each elements in the list . its like 'Elemant1','Element2',

Comment: Where you got strings for array `ww`? You did the splitting?

Comment: Guys i got solution its like re.sub('\+([^ ]*)','',str(c11))

Comment: I added a solution without using `regex`. Please find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quit simple .

just using re .

re.sub('+([^ ]*)','',str(c11))

Thats it . Thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

```
ww = list(map(lambda x: '' if x in c11 else x, c11))
```

Comment: Not working man its output is   as bellow:     >>> list(map(lambda x: '' if x in c11 else x, c11))
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Answer (score 0):

Or using a list comprehension:

```
new_cc = [element if element not in ww else '' for element in cc11]
```

Comment: I think I had them the wrong way around, try it again now

Comment: its not replacing anything in c11 , i want those values in c11 should become '' if those values are in also in ww

Comment: It's putting them in a new list, new_cc. If you want them in the cc11 set the list comprehension equal to that instead

Comment: I have added the expected output , kindly look into it

Comment: Guys i got solution its like re.sub('\+([^ ]*)','',str(c11))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need,

```
for index, element in enumerate(c11):
    if element in ww:
        c11[index] = ""
```

Comment: its not replacing anything in c11 , i want those values in c11 should become '' if those values are in also in ww

Comment: Its not replacing anything in c11 , c11 is still same

Comment: u have to use re module to replace

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: Expected output as posted with question , kindly take a look

Answer (score 0):

This outputs as you want it to be. I didn't use `re` here. But this seems to be simpler.

```
c11=[' YandexBot/3.0, +http://yandex.com/bots', ' Win64, x64', ' AhrefsBot/5.2, +http://ahrefs.com/robot/', ' Android 7.1.2, Redmi 4 Build/N2G47H', ' Android 7.0, EVA-L09 Build/HUAWEIEVA-L09', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi Note 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Googlebot/2.1, +http://www.google.com/bot.html', ' Android 6.0.1, CPH1701 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-J500F Build/MMB29M', ' uCrawler/1.0 , +https://blog.ucoz.ru/upolicy', ' SurdotlyBot/1.0, +http://sur.ly/bot.html', ' Opera Mini/8.0.40377/85.73, U', ' Pinterestbot/1.0, +http://www.pinterest.com/bot.html', ' Android 7.0, SM-J701F Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0.1, Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-A500H Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.1.1, SM-T385 Build/NMF26X', ' SemrushBot/1.2~bl, +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html', ' Android 6.0.1, ONE A2003 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.0, Redmi Note 4 Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0, QMobile X32 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 5.1.1, SM-J200F Build/LMY47X', ' WOW64, rv:40.0', ' Android 6.0, IK-7216 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 7.0, SM-J710FN Build/NRD90M']
ww=["http://yandex.com/bots',", "http://ahrefs.com/robot/',", "http://www.google.com/bot.html',", "https://blog.ucoz.ru/upolicy',", "http://sur.ly/bot.html',", "http://www.pinterest.com/bot.html',", "http://www.semrush.com/bot.html',"]
ww = [' +' + i.replace("',","") for i in ww]
for i in c11:
  sub = i.split(',')
  pos = c11.index(i)
  for j in ww:
    if sub[1] == j:
      i = i.replace(j, "")
      c11[pos] = i

print(c11)
```

**Output:**

```
[' YandexBot/3.0, ', ' Win64, x64', ' AhrefsBot/5.2, ', ' Android 7.1.2, Redmi 4 Build/N2G47H', ' Android 7.0, EVA-L09 Build/HUAWEIEVA-L09', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi Note 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Googlebot/2.1, ', ' Android 6.0.1, CPH1701 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, Redmi 4 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-J500F Build/MMB29M', ' uCrawler/1.0 , ', ' SurdotlyBot/1.0, ', ' Opera Mini/8.0.40377/85.73, U', ' Pinterestbot/1.0, ', ' Android 7.0, SM-J701F Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0.1, Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P', ' Android 6.0.1, SM-A500H Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.1.1, SM-T385 Build/NMF26X', ' SemrushBot/1.2~bl, ', ' Android 6.0.1, ONE A2003 Build/MMB29M', ' Android 7.0, Redmi Note 4 Build/NRD90M', ' Android 6.0, QMobile X32 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 5.1.1, SM-J200F Build/LMY47X', ' WOW64, rv:40.0', ' Android 6.0, IK-7216 Build/MRA58K', ' Android 7.0, SM-J710FN Build/NRD90M']
```